# How do you specify a Pandas DataFrame schema/structure in a docstring?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, docstring

I'd like to describe the DataFrame structure my Python function expects, and a verbal description like:

```py
def myfun(input):
    """ Does a thing.
    Parameters
    ----------
    input : pandas.DataFrame
        column 1 is called 'thing1' and it is of dtype 'i4'"
    """
    ...
```

feels error prone.  Is there a conventional way to describe it?  I don't see anything in the Pandas docstring documentation.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/contributing_docstring.html

Comment: This link is good general advice, but doesn't appear to describe how to specify DataFrame schema in docstrings.

Answer (score 14):

Since there is no official standard, my answer is inevitable, **opinionated**.

---

**ANSWER**

I suggest using a description based on the repr() of a Series because each dataframe can be described as a collection of series. It should also be based on the [pandas docstring guide for developers](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/contributing_docstring.html).

```
def myfun(input):
    """ Does a thing.
    Parameters
    ----------
    input : pandas.DataFrame
        Index:
            RangeIndex
        Columns:
            Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
            Name: Integer, dtype: int64
            Name: Float, dtype: float64
            Name: Object, dtype: object

    """
```

Example dataframe:

```
data = [[pd.Timestamp(2020, 1, 1), 1, 1.1, "A"],
        [pd.Timestamp(2020, 1, 2), 2, 2.2, "B"]]
input = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=data, columns=['Date', 'Integer', 'Float', 'Object'])
```

Output:

```
    Date        Integer     Float   Object
0   2020-01-01  1           1.1     A
1   2020-01-02  2           2.2     B
```

---

**GENERAL DEFINITION**

```
<dataframe name>: pandas.DataFrame
    Index:
        <__repr__ of Index>
            <Optional: Description of index data>
    Columns:
        <last line of __repr__ of pd.Series object of first column>
            <Optional: Description of column data>
        ...
        <last line of __repr__ of pd.Series object of last column>
            <Optional: Description of column data>
```

---

**EXPLANATION**

There is a detailed discussion of how table data can be standardized. From this discussion, standards such as [ISO/IEC 11179](http://metadata-standards.org/11179/), the [JSON Table Schema](http://dataprotocols.org/json-table-schema/) and the [W3C Tabular Data Model](https://www.w3.org/TR/tabular-data-model/) emerged. However, they are not perfect for describing a dataframe in a docstring. For example, you need to consider relationships with other tables, which is important for database applications, but not for Pandas dataframes.

My proposed repr-based approach has several advantages:

- It respects the opinion of the core developers of Pandas. The repr was what we should see about the object.
- It is efficient. Let's face it, documentation is difficult. Automation is very simple with this approach. An example can be found below.
- It is evolving. If the repr ever changes, the docstring also changes.
- It is expandable. If you like to include additional meta data, the dataframe object has many more attributes that you can include.

Example of an automatically generated docstring with additional meta data:

```
df = input.copy()
df = df.set_index('Date')
docstring = 'Index:\n'
docstring = docstring + f'    {df.index}\n'
docstring = docstring + 'Columns:\n'
for col in df.columns:    
    docstring = docstring + f'    Name: {df[col].name}, dtype={df[col].dtype}, nullable: {df[col].hasnans}\n'
```

Output:

```
Index:
    DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
Columns:
    Name: Integer, dtype=int64, nullable: False
    Name: Float, dtype=float64, nullable: False
    Name: Object, dtype=object, nullable: False
```

Comment: Seems reasonable and it looks nice.  It would be great to see something from the PyData library/maintainers.