# pandas DataFrame documentation generation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-sphinx

I am maintaining a pandas Dataframe for storing ML features.

It is important to add the semanthic of each column, so a user can understand the meaning of each feature, how it was calculated, what is its source etc.

Needless to say that the DataDrame is produced by some business logic and is evolved over time (new features are being added).

**Is there a way to auto-generate (ex: sphinx) documentation for a DataFrame, like there is for functions and classes?**

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/54971410/407651

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but could be useful anyways: https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling

Comment: Thanks @mzjn, I am searching for solution to the same problem that your link OP is looking for. But it seems there is no such (except of idea). Thanks RJ, but this is not a what I am looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you want to extend the DataFrame class and add your own attribute with the @property decorator for every named column and provide docstrings.  Then you can use sphinx to generate docs for your class.